# Move with object until finger is unhold or untaped

Tags: windows-phone-7, xna, position, windows-phone-7.1, gesture

I have this:

```
private void HandleTouchInput()
{
  while (TouchPanel.IsGestureAvailable)
  {
  // read the next gesture from the queue
  GestureSample gesture = TouchPanel.ReadGesture();
  switch (gesture.GestureType)
  {
     case GestureType.Hold:
     // left
     if (gesture.Position.X < 100 && gesture.Position.Y < 100)
     {
        ship.Position.X -= 5;
     }
     break;
   }
}
```

(HandleTouchInput is in Update method)

How can I repeate code in switch until "finger" is untaped (unhold) from screen? I dont want to change position just once, I want to changing it the user still pressing at exact position. Thanks

Comment: I updated code snippet hope it helps

Comment: A Hold is when you touch the screen for 1 second. This gesture will only occur once. Keeping your finger on the screen will not fire a Hold every second. You can again use the Position property to determine where the player holds. If you want to do something for as long as a finger is on the screen, you’ll need to use raw input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As NitWit suggested, you'll need to use raw input, e.g., like this:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // TouchPanel.GetState() should be called only once per frame
    TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();

    HandleInput(touchCollection);
}

private void HandleInput(TouchCollection touchCollection)
{
    if (touchCollection.Count == 0)
    {
        return;
    }

    TouchLocation touchLocation = touchCollection[0];
    Vector2 touchPosition = touchLocation.Position;

    switch (touchLocation.State)
    {
        case TouchLocationState.Moved:
        case TouchLocationState.Pressed:
        case TouchLocationState.Released:
            if (touchPosition.X < 100 && touchPosition.Y < 100)
            {
                ship.Position.X -= 5;
            }

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: O no, you gave away the fun ;)